# Why does the array_filter function work only for last directory in a loop in PHP?

Tags: php

While looping through various directories, I used `array_filter` to put the directories' filenames into an array, then we proceed to the next directory;

The value of $HALLO1 is a value that is read from an array.

One thing I noticed is that when array_filter() is operated on $HALLO1 and in the case where $HALLO1 is equal to an array of directories, the var_dump() function does not list files in the first directories but only list the files contained in last directory. However, when $HALLO1 is equal to one and only directory the array_filter() works and lists all the files contained in that directory. Why is that ?

```
<?php

foreach ($CC1 as $directory)  {
    $GG1 = strval($CC1[$dd]);
    $HALLO1 = $GG1;
    echo "HALLO1 = " . $HALLO1 ;
    $iterator = new DirectoryIterator(dirname($HALLO1));
    //*****************************************************
    $f_files = array_filter(glob("$HALLO1*"), 'is_file');
    var_dump($f_files);
    //*****************************************************
    ++$dd; 
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Try: `$f_files[] = array_filter(glob("$HALLO1*"), 'is_file');` Does that do the trick for you?

Comment: Where is the closing `}`?

Comment: And why are you setting a directoryIterator when you're using glob()?

Comment: Does `$HALLO1` contain a directory prefix? If not, it will be interpreted relative to the current directory. Maybe that's not where you intend.

Comment: I don't see how `$HALLO1` could ever be an array when it is set from `$GG1` which in it's turn is set from `strval($CC1[$dd])` and should therefore always be a string. Anyhow; `array_filter()` wouldn't work because `$HALLO1` is converted to a string in the pattern definition for `glob()` and converting an array to a string returns `"Array"` which probably isn't a valid directory.

From what I understand you're trying to do you would probably be better of using this code:

`$f_files = array_filter(glob("{" . implode(",", $CC1) . "}/*", GLOB_BRACE), "is_file")`

Answer (score 1):

Because you're overwriting $f_files in each iteration

```
$f_files = array()
foreach ($CC1 as $directory)  {
    $GG1 = strval($CC1[$dd]);
    $HALLO1 = $GG1;
    $f_files = array_merge($f_files, array_filter(glob("$HALLO1*"), 'is_file'));
}
var_dump($f_files);
```

Comment: @Abigail - if an answer doesn't work for you, don't try to edit the answer to say "it doesn't work".... that's what comments are for

Comment: I incorporated the new definition of $f_files but it seems that the var_dump($f_files) shows only an array(0) for the first directory and an array(14) for the next one. Although the first directory has files in it. I tried: $f_files[$dd] = array(); but that does not resolve the problem either.

Comment: One thing I notice is that the program will output files in an array when the directory is listed (in the output) as for example: C:\Temp\TEST\ .  (with a dot next to the directory name) otherwise is the directory is spelt C:\Temp\TEST with a dot an a dot dot (..) in each of the following lines then the result is different. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it is definitely a problem with overwriting; It seems that while going through the loop, there is some sort of flag that should be set equal to true. I tried incorporating a function in order to calculate the directories size in bytes but it gives me 0 bytes for the first 2 directories. The last one gives me a big number and gives me all the files in an array form.